# Cannot convert string to `System.DayOfWeek`

Tags: c#, list

```
List<string> delivery_name4 = new List<string>();
List<string> delivery_name44 = new List<string>();
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("UpdateDetails");
for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
     {
           delivery_name4.Add(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim());
     }                 
           delivery_name44 = delivery_name4.Select(item => ((DayOfWeek)item).ToString().ToList());
```

The `delivery_name4` contains values from 0 to 6 and they repeat. I'm trying to convert the values like 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc. But I'm getting the error:

> cannot convert string to System.DayOfWeek

Comment: Your question content is not enough. please provide more details.

Comment: maybe something like: ```Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek),5)``` results in "friday"

Comment: I dont just need friday. the list contains 100's of values from 0 to 6 and all of them should be converter to day

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the strings to integers before you can cast to `DayOfWeek`:

```
delivery_name44 = delivery_name4
    .Select(item => ((DayOfWeek)int.Parse(item)).ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<char>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I'm getting the above error when I'm trying to int parse the item

Comment: @Nakshatra See this working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k34A3B